# Uploading image should be stored on DB with Bit (Encoded)?

Tags: javascript, php, encoding

1. This code run but the image was not display
2. why the image was not display

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> img bit</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="backend.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you have shown image? I am not able to see <img tag in your html ?

Comment: hello Furqan! yeah corect ..i cant understant this concept like this link tutorial http://kennykee.com/92/saving-image-to-database-using-php/

Comment: Since the client will be sent to `backend.php` with the image, where is the php source code? Any attempt to save to a database?

Comment: hmm yeah i tried @NewToJs

Comment: Can you edit post and add your server side code as well?

Comment: We need to see your attempt (`backend.php`) so that we can find the problem and explain why it isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

1. This has nothing to do with encryption. `enctype` refers to encoding, not encryption. [The distinction between encryption and encoding is very important](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded)!
2. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is what I've used on the `<form>` tag in every functioning file upload system I've ever written.
3. What does `backend.php` do? That's almost certainly where your problem lies if your files aren't uploading.